# Django project doesn't show up with Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi, web-deployment

I've installed Apache and mod_wsgi on windows xp service pack 3 and added these line to my httpd.conf :

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Documents and Settings/X/My Documents/Downloads/Foo/Foo/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/Documents and Settings/X/My Documents/Downloads/Foo"

<Directory "C:/Documents and Settings/X/My Documents/Downloads/Foo/Foo">
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

but when I open localhost on my firefox, it shows Apache's `It Works!` message, what should I do to run my project on localhost ?

**EDIT :**

I checked and recognized that my project's path is not included in `PYTHONPATH`. Isn't the line `WSGIPythonPath ...` expected to add the address to `PYTHONPATH` ?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so my setup is in linux so this is not tested on windows, but:

I did not see your LoadModule statement

File: **httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

modwsgi wont work without that.

Also: the your grant statement seems a bit suspicious.
In the [wsgi configuration guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) suggests using a Directory directive for allowing this access to your mod_wsgi application.

```
<Directory "C:/Documents and Settings/X/My Documents/Downloads/Foo/Foo/">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Finally:**

Make your life easy down the road.

- configure apache in worker mode
- configure mod_wsgi in daemon mode.
- profit

Might I suggest watching this PyCon talk [Making Apache suck less for hosting Python web applications](http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/#link-qhyk) from 'the-man' Graham. I wish I knew all of that stuff years ago.

Note: To figure out if you have apache in mpm worker mode.

```
httpd.exe -V
```

look for the "Server MPM" value of worker.

Answer (score -1):

Django runs on port 8000 so you'll want to do two things.  First, you need to run the server by entering into your console `python manage.py runserver`.  Second, you need to direct your browser to `localhost:8000`.

As an aside, you don't need Apache to run a simple, local development environment.  Django has its own server built in that you can leverage.

Comment: thanks, but I want to run django on Apache, I've Already run my project with runserver

Comment: I see.  Well, I'm going to recommend that you don't.  Setting up a Windows XP environment is a bad idea.  One, its no longer supported.  You need to move to a more modern operating system.  If you can't, that's fine, but I wouldn't invest to much time trying to learn a deprecated system.  Two, a production Django environment would be better off if it were on a linux server.  You will benefit from a larger support group and better compatibility.  I know this doesn't answer your question but I hope this advice can still help you move forward.